# Image max-width gives scrollbar with no scrollheight

Tags: html, css

I need an image with max width of 100% of its container and keep aspect ratio.
When i do, i get a scrollbar with nothing to scroll (disabled scrollbar) when the window gets at a specific width.

When the image`s width is being ajusted (because of the max-width) and the height is just enhough to fit, then make the window 2 pixel less high.
Let me give you a video because it is hard to explain:
https://dump.video/i/4otCA8.mp4

From this point:
- Chrome gives an enabled scrollbar. When resizing the height 1 pixel larger now, the scrollbar wil be disabled. After reload: disabled scrollbar.
- Firefox gives a disabled scrollbar imidiatly, even after reload.

This gives very anoying flickering with animations and stuff.

Tried:
- overflow-x hidden on container/body
- a lot of other tweaks

Needs:
- class form must be flex

Setting fixed height fixes it but gives unwanted result: no auto sized image and broken aspect ratio

Minimum example:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            * {
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
                box-sizing:border-box;
            }

            img {
                display:block;
                max-width:100%;
            }

            .container {
                width:40%;
                min-height:100vh;
                background:#ccc;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="http://formbuilder.local.nl/api/Formbuilder.Tests.color?&color=blue&" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So my question is:
How to get rid of the scrollbar using width:100% on the image and without using fixed height on the contrainer or image field.

Comment: keep in mind percentage values depends on the parent, your div doesn't have any set width so `max-width:100%;` wont' take effect

Comment: Where is the parent container? what size should the parent be?

Comment: Sorry, missed that in the example. The container in my app has fixed width. Will update the example right now

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to get rid of the scrollbar without using fixed height on the contrainer or image field. The container can be larger than 100vh and min-height doesn`t fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can use height:

```
img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

}

Comment: That will break the aspect ratio

Comment: You have to fix container height in pixel.

Answer (score 0):

So, what's happening is that you are not reseting the layout, meaning, the layout will start with a default margin around.

So, my advice is to reset it by doing the following:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

To see a working example, look at the codepen I'v made. 
https://codepen.io/pedro-figueiredo/pen/MMYddE

Comment: Your example breaks the aspect ratio of the image.